# How do you remove a nested element from a json string using system.text.json C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

I have a json string that has nested values:

```
{
  "card": {
    "number": "411111111111111111",
    "expirationMonth": null,
    "expirationYear": null,
    "securityCode": null
  }
}
```

I want to remove expirationMonth, expirationYear, securityCode so that only card: number remain. but I can't find any example of how to do this with system.text.json that aren't wickedly complex and involve basically writing your own extension library.

Here is what I've tried:

```
JsonObject requestJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(jsonString);
                requestJson.Remove("expirationMonth");
                requestJson.Remove("expirationYear");
                requestJson.Remove("securityCode");
```

But since the elements are nested JsonObject.Remove does nothing.

Comment: `requestJson["card"].Remove...`

Comment: Man I wish it was that easy! but that doesn't work

Comment: If anyone else comes across this page after searching, I also found that I can ignore null values from the underlying object when serializing and that fixed my issue as well.     var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true, 
        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
    };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote with 2 ways

Use system.text.json

```
JsonObject requestJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(jsonString);

var card = requestJson["card"].AsObject();

card.Remove("expirationMonth");

card.Remove("securityCode");
card.Remove("expirationYear");
```

use Newtonsoft.Json

```
var objd = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
 objd.Value<JObject>("card").Remove("expirationMonth");
 objd.Value<JObject>("card").Remove("expirationYear");
 objd.Value<JObject>("card").Remove("securityCode");

Console.WriteLine(objd);
```

Comment: LOL - I knew there was going to be a Newtonsoft answer! If I was using that I wouldn't have had to post the question. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: @AdamWilliams, i added with way use system.text.json

Comment: Fantastic! that is exactly what I needed - thank you so much. Been searching for an answer all day.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot about a root property. should be

```
((JsonObject)requestJson["card"]).Remove("expirationMonth");
//... and so on
```

Comment: This also works. I'm not sure which is better - but again appreciate the response.